# Passing arguments in jersey application while running war

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, servlets, jersey, war

My project code is written in jersey, so I use to create a war file and deploy it on Tomcat to run it. Due to some requirement I need to pass arguments while running the application. Can we do this in war like the way we can do this in jar application.

Comment: What type of arguments are you trying to pass and when do you want to pass them?

Comment: One way is to simply use environment variables.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I want to pass DB properties during run time in Hibernate.cfg.xml. Please help if you know about this.